# Eclipse deletes files under WEB-INF on every run

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm trying to setup Maven with my GWT project but every time that I start debugging, it deletes web.xml and other files that are required to start.

Code fragment related to build from my `pom.xml` :

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>  
                <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What is `${webappDirectory}`? Why are you configuring the `maven-compiler-plugin` with `<webXml>`?

Comment: Modify your `outputDirectory` to something else rather than `${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/`.

Comment: I removed it and it still compilling but web.xml is still deleted on debugging.

<webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>

Comment: For the moment, I removed maven and everythings works well.